# Javascript date , what to consider in comparing months?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Compare dates, and if enddate belongs to next month return boolean.

## Example

startdate = January 15, 2020
enddate = February 02, 2020

Output : enddate is a future month

startdate = January 15, 2020
enddate = January 27, 2020

Output: enddate is not a future month.

startdate = January 15, 2020
enddate = March 23, 2020

Output: enddate is a future month.

## Code

```
const startdate = new Date();
const enddate = new Date(this.request.periodEndDate);
const enddateMonth = enddate.getMonth();
const startdatemonth = startdate.getMonth();

if(enddateMonth > startdatemonth) {
    console.log("future month")
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the code relates to the description. Where's startdate or enddate?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @Richard , please check the update one thanks

Comment: Are you interested in leap years, alternative calendars/locales, and similar shenanigans?

Comment: @Richard yes Sir

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isFutureMonth = (startDate, endDate) => {
    const getYearMonth = date => date.getYear() * 100 + date.getMonth();

    const start = getYearMonth(startDate);
    const end = getYearMonth(endDate);

    return end > start;
}


console.log(isFutureMonth(new Date('2020-01-15'), new Date('2020-01-27')));

console.log(isFutureMonth(new Date('2020-01-15'), new Date('2020-02-27')));
```

Came up to this. Does seem to work just fine.

Multiplication by 100 is needed to avoid miscalculation where year=2019,month=2 would be equal to year=2020,month=1, which seems good enough for comparison if it's future month. I'd be happy proven to be wrong if it doesn't.

Comment: isnt there is a better implementation to this like using moment ?

Comment: @MarkLuthberg maybe there is. But this is quite simple to be honest.

Comment: what is the difference with you code with my example above ? what things you have considered? thanks

Comment: This handles years as well. Your code would return that `2019-10-01` is future month compared to `2020-05-01`, which is clearly wrong.